# Send million events to Azure event hub every 5 seconds

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I have a simple requirement, 1 million devices need to send a simple heartbeat to the event hub every 5 seconds, that works out to 200000 events per second. Since 1 throughput unit supports only 1000 events\sec, do I really need to purchase 200 throughput units to implement a simple heartbeat mechanism?

I'm really wondering about the claim of event hub supporting millions of events per second, how is that possible if a throughput unit only supports 1000. I need a HUGE number of throughput units and that's going to burn every last dollar. Unless I'm really missing something.

Comment: check these out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35520002/should-the-event-hub-have-same-number-of-partitions-as-throughput-units  https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2014/07/18/getting-acquainted-with-azure-service-bus-event-hubs/

Comment: Have you looked at IoT Hub?  Out of curiosity, why send an heartbeat every 5 seconds?

Comment: Eventhub does support your use case and you already seem to know how to accomplish that. Is this just a price rant? (I agree that prices are really high but this is not the place to complain about prices.)

Comment: You'd pay 12000$ per month for those events. You would pay a tiny amount if you ran that solution on your own server (likely, an 80$/month server could handle all load and you need 2 for HA). Cloud is not cheap.